# Как лучше сделать мутации в Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Есть разные action: fetch, fetchAll, update, create, delete
Как лучше: сделать одну мутацию setError и туда записывать ошибки, если таковые есть, или сделать разные мутации: setFetchError, setFetchAllError, usetUdateError, setCreateError, setDeleteError?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше создать мутацию для обработки ошибок и прокидывать ей код экшена и текст ошибки чтобы не плодить однотипные мутации.

```
handleError(state, { action, error } ) {
    //do something
}
```